# Failed to process package 'rosconsole':

Tags: cmake, package, ros, catkin, log4cxx

I have installed ROS noetic on raspian buster but it get gives error when this command is implemented as per the procedure mentioned in

http://wiki.ros.org/noetic/Installation/Source

> ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release

It succesfully goes till 61 ros packages and gives a cmake error at 'rosconsole'

The error goes like this

```
==> Processing catkin package: 'rosconsole'
==> Building with env: '/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh'
==> cmake /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src/rosconsole -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rosconsole -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3 -G Unix Makefiles in '/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/rosconsole'
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rosconsole
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated
-- This workspace overlays: /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python3 (found suitable version "3.7.3", minimum required is "3") 
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python3
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/em.py
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/rosconsole/test_results
-- Forcing gtest/gmock from source, though one was otherwise available.
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/googletest': gtests will be built
-- Found gmock sources under '/usr/src/googletest': gmock will be built
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python3 (found version "3.7.3") 
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests3
-- catkin 0.8.10
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- rosconsole backend: print
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
LOG4CXX_LIBRARIES
    linked by target "rosconsole-thread_test" in directory /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src/rosconsole
    linked by target "rosconsole-utest" in directory /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src/rosconsole

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/rosconsole/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/rosconsole/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
<== Failed to process package 'rosconsole': 
  Command '['/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh', 'cmake', '/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src/rosconsole', '-DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rosconsole', '-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated', '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3', '-G', 'Unix Makefiles']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

Reproduce this error by running:
==> cd /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/rosconsole && /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh cmake /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src/rosconsole -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rosconsole -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3 -G 'Unix Makefiles'

Command failed, exiting.
```

Tried every possible thing, cant resolve the issue.

In addition to this, rospy package is successfully installed and sourced but cant be imported. Is there any way i can import rospy, I am a total beginner. any help is appreciated. Rospy succussed installation log is as follows

```
==> Processing catkin package: 'rospy'
==> Building with env: '/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh'
Makefile exists, skipping explicit cmake invocation...
==> make cmake_check_build_system in '/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/rospy'
==> make -j4 -l4 in '/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/rospy'
==> make install in '/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/rospy'
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: "Release-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3"
-- Installing: /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/_setup_util.py
-- Installing: /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh
-- Installing: /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/setup.bash
-- Installing: /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/local_setup.bash
-- Installing: /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/setup.sh
-- Installing: /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/local_setup.sh
-- Installing: /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/setup.zsh
-- Installing: /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/local_setup.zsh
-- Installing: /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/.rosinstall
-- Up-to-date: /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/lib/pkgconfig/rospy.pc
-- Up-to-date: /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/rospy/cmake/rospyConfig.cmake
-- Up-to-date: /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/rospy/cmake/rospyConfig-version.cmake
-- Up-to-date: /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/rospy/package.xml
+ cd /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src/ros_comm/rospy
+ mkdir -p /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/lib/python3/dist-packages
+ /usr/bin/env PYTHONPATH=/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/lib/python3/dist-packages:/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/rospy/lib/python3/dist-packages:/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/lib/python3/dist-packages CATKIN_BINARY_DIR=/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/rospy /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src/ros_comm/rospy/setup.py egg_info --egg-base /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/rospy build --build-base /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/rospy install --root=/ --install-layout=deb --prefix=/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated --install-scripts=/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/bin
running egg_info
writing /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/rospy/rospy.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/rospy/rospy.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/rospy/rospy.egg-info/top_level.txt
reading manifest file '/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/rospy/rospy.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file '/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/rospy/rospy.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running build
running build_py
running build_scripts
running install
running install_lib
running install_egg_info
removing '/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/lib/python3/dist-packages/rospy-1.15.15.egg-info' (and everything under it)
Copying /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/rospy/rospy.egg-info to /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/lib/python3/dist-packages/rospy-1.15.15.egg-info
Skipping SOURCES.txt
running install_scripts
changing mode of /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/bin/rosconsole to 755
-- Up-to-date: /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/rospy/rosbuild/rospy.cmake
-- Up-to-date: /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/rospy/rosbuild/scripts/genmsg_py.py
-- Up-to-date: /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/rospy/rosbuild/scripts/gensrv_py.py
-- Up-to-date: /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/rospy/rosbuild/scripts/genutil.py
<== Finished processing package [54 of 184]: 'rospy'
```

I did
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade

tried the procedure from scratch twice from

Everytime it get stuck on this rosconsole package. All i want is to import rospy in script as i am modifying a script which uses rospy.

Comment: "_CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND. Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files: `LOG4CXX_LIBRARIES`_" That's what you should investigate. I don't think there's enough info in your post for anyone to help you further without going outside of this post to do detective work in how rosconsole is set up to work.

Comment: what information should i provide? and how to resolve LOG4cxx_Libraries

Answer (score 0):

You need to install log4cxx. On Ubuntu this should work:

```
sudo apt install liblog4cxx-dev
```